# Criar Componente DELPHI em Tempo de Execução

Tags: delphi

```
texto := 'object DWResponseTranslator1: TDWResponseTranslator ' +
  'ElementAutoReadRootIndex = True'+
  'ElementRootBaseIndex = -1'+
  'RequestOpen = rtGet'+
  'RequestInsert = rtPost'+
  'RequestEdit = rtPost'+
  'RequestDelete = rtDelete'+
  'FieldDefs = <'+  
  '  item'+
  '    FieldName = 'ID''+
  '    ElementName = 'ID''+
  '    ElementIndex = -1'+
  '    FieldSize = 6'+
  '    Precision = 0'+
  '    DataType = ovInteger'+
  '    Required = False'+
  '  end'+  
  'left = 288'+
  'top = 32'+
  'end';

novoComponente := Criar_Componente(Texto);
```

tenho essa estrutura copiada de um compontente designer
é possivel com esse texto criar um componente delphi em tempo de execucao ??

Comment: Conforme já respondido pelo @Roberto, você precisa criar a classe na mão e setar as propriedades conforme desejado. Uma solução para automatizar um pouco este processo seria utilizar o plugin GExperts, tem uma opção de clicar com o botão direito do Mouse e "Component to code", ele já retorna todo o código necessário.

Answer (score 2):

Para criar componente em tempo de execução, faço da seguinte forma:

```
var
  DWResponseTranslator1: TDWResponseTranslator;
begin
  DWResponseTranslator1 := TDWResponseTranslator.Create({Aqui é necessário colocar os parâmetros de construção});
  DWResponseTranslator1.ElementAutoReadRootIndex := True;
  DWResponseTranslator1.ElementRootBaseIndex := -1;

  ...

end;
```

No caso da propriedade `FieldDefs` tem que ser criado um `Field` por vez e adicionar ao `FieldDefs`.

Answer (score 1):

Para extrair o código DFM de um componente:

```
function ComponentToStringProc(Component: TComponent): string;
var
  BinStream:TMemoryStream;
  StrStream: TStringStream;
  s: string;
begin
  BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    StrStream := TStringStream.Create(s);
    try
      BinStream.WriteComponent(Component);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      ObjectBinaryToText(BinStream, StrStream);
      StrStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= StrStream.DataString;
    finally
      StrStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    BinStream.Free
  end;
end;
```

Para criar o componente a partir do código DFM:

```
function StringToComponentProc(Value: string): TComponent;
var
  StrStream:TStringStream;
  BinStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  StrStream := TStringStream.Create(Value);
  try
    BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ObjectTextToBinary(StrStream, BinStream);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= BinStream.ReadComponent(nil);
    finally
      BinStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    StrStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

**Para utilizar faça o seguinte:**

Obter o código DFM de um Edit;

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Text := ComponentToStringProc(Edit1);
end;
```

---

Para criar o Edit a partir do DFM obtido:

```
procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  EdtX: TEdit;
begin
  EdtX := StringToComponentProc(Memo1.Text) as TEdit;
  EdtX.Parent := Form1;
end;
```

No initialization registre a classe TEdit ou dos componentes que desejar.

```
initialization
  RegisterClass(TEdit);
```

---

Fonte: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/ComponentToString_(Delphi)

Answer (score 0):

Baseado na string pura você pode ir implementando conforme a necessidade de outras classes aparecerem.

No exemplo a seguir estou considerando criar um componente baseado na `TEdit` justamente por não possuir esse componente que demonstrou na pergunta, mas a ideia é a mesma.

```
function TForm14.Criar_Componente(aComponente: String): TComponent;
var
  vComponente : TArray<String>;
begin
  aComponente := aComponente.Substring(0, aComponente.Length - 3);
  vComponente := aComponente.Split([' ']);

  if (vComponente[2] = 'TEdit') then
  begin
    TEdit(Result)          := TEdit.Create(Self);
    TEdit(Result).Parent   := Self;
    TEdit(Result).Name     := vComponente[1].Replace(':', EmptyStr);
    TEdit(Result).Left     := StrToInt(vComponente[6]);
    TEdit(Result).Top      := StrToInt(vComponente[10]);
    TEdit(Result).Width    := StrToInt(vComponente[14]);
    TEdit(Result).Height   := StrToInt(vComponente[18]);
    TEdit(Result).TabOrder := StrToInt(vComponente[22]);
    TEdit(Result).Text     := vComponente[26];
  end;
end;
```

O `Split([' ']);` vai lhe entregar um Array de dados, bastando pegar cada posição equivalente a cada propriedade, isto é "procedural", não conheço outra forma.

Como o resultado da função é um `TComponente` ele vai atender a maioria das classes.

Você poderá criar overloads para classes diferentes se desejar.

Para utilizar bastaria:

```
var
  vComponente : TComponent;
const
  _COMPONENTE =   'object Lb_Teste: TEdit'+
                  '  Left = 402'+
                  '  Top = 8'+
                  '  Width = 225'+
                  '  Height = 21'+
                  '  TabOrder = 0'+
                  '  Text = ''Teste'+
                  'end';
begin
  vComponente := Criar_Componente(_COMPONENTE);
end;
```